# Unable to unit test firebase function in Sinon

Tags: javascript, node.js, firebase, sinon, sinon-chai

I am trying to unit test a JavaScript promise, that contains a firebase query, using mocha, chai, sinon. I am trying to mock the database using sinon rather than actually making a request to the database. However, I am unable to implement it correctly.

Here is my promise in the file '/services/pr_services:

```
exports.getUserInfo = (userId) => {
return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    const userProfile = {};
    const userProfileRef = database.ref('profiles').child(userId);
    userProfileRef.once('value', (snap) => {
        if (snap.exists()) {
            const userProfileData = snap.val();
            resolve(userProfile);
        } else {
            reject();
        }
    });
});
};
```

The variable `database` contains the database configuration like credentials, database url, etc

Here is my code for the test case:

```
 const chai = require('chai');
 const sinon = require('sinon');
 const admin = require('firebase-admin');
 const database = require('../database');
 const services = require('../services/pr_services');


const should = chai.should();

describe('Database functions', () => {
let adminInitStub;

before(() => {
    adminInitStub = sinon.stub(admin, 'initializeApp');
});

describe('get profile info', () => {
    it('should return a non empty object', (done) => {

        beforeEach(() => {
            services.getUserInfo = sinon.stub();
        });

        afterEach(() => {
            services.getUserInfo.reset();
        });

        const userId = 'jim123';
        const snap = {
            name: 'Jim Dani',
            address: 'Porto'
        };
        const userProfileRef = database.ref('profiles').child(userId);
        userProfileRef.once('value').returns(Promise.resolve(snap));

        services.getUserInfo
            .then(info => {
                info.should.be.a('object');
                info.should.equal(snap);
                done();
            })
            .catch(err => {
                should.not.exist(err);
                done();
            });
    });
});


after(() => {
    adminInitStub.restore();
    test.cleanup();
});
});
```

Can anyone point out where I am going wrong and kindly point me in right direction.

Thanks.

Comment: When you say you're testing a "firebase function", do you actually mean that you're writing code for Cloud Functions for Firebase?

Comment: I have a simple firebase query that fetches data from the database. I'm not writing any cloud functions. I just want to be able to test that query using the mock-up technique rather than actually hitting the database.
specifically this query here - `database.ref('profiles').child(userId).once('value')`